# Applescript Select Checkbox Enable Access for accessibility devices

Tags: user-interface, applescript

I am trying to automatically select the checkbox that will enable access for accessibility devices.

[image]

Below is my code which is opening the correct settings window. However, it is not setting the checkbox.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell

tell application "System Events"

    set theCheckbox to checkbox "Enable access for assistive devices"
    tell theCheckbox
        if not (its value as boolean) then click theCheckbox
    end tell

end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to set it to enabled

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to set UI elements enabled to true
```

Comment: You don't need to go into System Preferences